# Generate argument names from list of types to forward to another function

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to generate a function that forwards its arguments to another function. I know that std::function does it somehow, but I cannot seem to find the right syntax myself.

It would be ok for my usecase to use som kind of template magic, but i want
the user to be able to get information on the calling types when they use the function, like std::function does.

My usecase uses class member functions, so a solution that only works in that context is accepted. I tried to created the smallest example code possible.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Macro usage cannot be changed 
#define ARGS int, int 

void otherFunction(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x << "," << y << "\n";
}

// This is the behaviour i want
void expectedImplementation(int _1, int _2) {
    otherFunction(_1, _2);
}

// This works, but it prevents the user to view the expected
// types in their IDE
template <typename ...Args>
void templateVersion(Args ... args) {
    otherFunction(args...);
}

// This is the version I cannot get to work
// It does not need to look like this, but it needs to get
// its argument types from 
//void func(ARGS) {
//    otherFunction(/*how?*/);
//}

int main() {
    expectedImplementation(1, 2);
    templateVersion(1, 2);
    //func(1, 2);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PWaPqK59v)

How do I accomplish this?

Edit:
The function that needs to be forwarded to is also different for each instance of the function.

Edit 2:
Ok, It seems like it's hard to specify the context without the context. [Here](https://github.com/mls-m5/thick-pointers/blob/ea81a58897f70f6e6de513ff4e82d082100771f5/test/rawtraitimplementation.h#L32) is the actual code that I want to generalize. [Here](https://github.com/mls-m5/thick-pointers/blob/ea81a58897f70f6e6de513ff4e82d082100771f5/include/trait.h#L39) Is the template magick stuff where it should fit in. No memory should be used, otherwise I would just use the solution I have now with template parameter packs.

Edit 3:
A [better example](https://godbolt.org/z/93vv3Was4):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define ARGS int, int 

struct Inner {
    void otherFunction(int x, int y) {
        std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Wrapper {
    Inner inner;

    // This works, but it prevents the user to view the expected
    // types in their ide
    template <typename ...Args>
    void templateVersion(Args ... args) {
        inner.otherFunction(args...);
    }

    // The concept I try to figure out
    void function(ARGS) { // It does not need to look exactly like this
                          // , but functionally it needs to be somithing like it
        // Forward the arguments to the `ìnner` class
    }
};

int main() {
    auto wrapper = Wrapper{};
    wrapper.templateVersion(10, 20);
}
```

Comment: This is more or less exactly what `std::function` does, unless there is some compiler-specific magic in the standard headers that helps the IDE, but you can go check for that.

Comment: @Quentin already checked, it does not work.

Comment: With `void (*func)(int, int) = otherFunction;` or `std::function<void(int, int)> func = otherFunction;`, you should have expected intellisense help (expect 2 `int`and not `Args...` as for `templateVersion`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Se my edit #2

Comment: Does your wrapper have to be a function, or can it be a callable class? If the latter, see this: https://godbolt.org/z/5PvvofKEs

Comment: @alagner Thanks. I reallize how hard it is to do a proper example. I wrote another one that is more close to the usecase. I need to call a member function, but I do not want to save a extra copy of a pointer to the object. So unfortunately that solution does not work. Sorry for not being able to give good examples from the beginning...

Comment: If your turn Wrapper in template, and then have `auto wrapper = Wrapper<int, int>{};` (or `Wrapper<void (int, int)>` or `Wrapper<void (Inner::*)(int, int)>`)

Answer (score 0):

Your macro `ARGS` does not define named arguments.  You cannot forward the type of unnamed arguments.  That's a limitation of the language.

Either forget about using macros, and change your function definiton:

```
void func(int a, int b) {
    otherFunction(a, b);
}
```

Or change the definition of the macro:

```
#define ARGS   int a, int b

void func(ARGS) {
    otherFunction(a, b);
}
```

That said, nothing beats the template solution.  Make sure you use perfect forwarding.

```
template <typename ...Args>
void templateVersion(Args&& ... args) {
   otherFunction(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: It's a shame, but I guess you're right. Your second example with the changed macro definition will not work without som messy way to separate the variable names out of the macro, and the number of arguments contained in ARGS can be different.

I guess i just keep the parameter pack solution from the beginning (with perfect forwarding of course).